# How can I delete files with odd names from directories?

Tags: linux, bash

Given files `0..9.txt` in directories `foo` and `bar`, how can I remove those which are odd?

I've come up with

```
find . -regextype egrep -regex ".*[0-9].txt"  | while read file; do    [ `expr match "$file" '[0-9]'`% 2 -eq 0 ] && rm -v "$file" ; done
```

But it doesn't work. I do not understand how properly set up finding the number in the full filename and check its parity.

Comment: What are examples of few add filenames?

Comment: anubhava, I think by "odd" the OP means an odd number (as opposed to even). Not odd in the sense of unusual.

Comment: this should do `".*[13579].txt"`

Comment: Seems like `find . -name '*[13579].txt'` is sufficient.  No need to do the regex.

Comment: It's much easier to solve problems if you try to break them down and solve individual pieces instead. If you try the parts of your script by themselves you'll see that `expr match file42.txt '[0-9]'` does not output 42, and `[ 2%2 -eq 0 ] && echo "even"` does not output 'even'.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```sh
find . -regextype egrep -regex ".*[0-9].txt" |
  while read file; do \
    n=$(basename $file .txt); \
    if [[ $((n % 2)) == 1 ]]; then \
      rm -v $file; \
    fi; \
  done
```

Answer (score 7):

```
find . -name '*[13579].txt' -delete
```

If your `find` doesn't support `-delete`, use:

```
find . -name '*[13579].txt' -exec rm {} \;
```

or

```
find . -name '*[13579].txt' -exec rm {} +
```